# If $Interior(A) \subseteq B \subseteq A$ then $A$ have $n$-connected components?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $A,B\subset \mathbb{C}$ and

1. $Interior(A) \subseteq B \subseteq A$.
2. If $\mathscr{M}$ be  a connected component of $A$, then $Interior(\mathscr{M}) \ne \phi $.
3. Let $B$ have, $n$ connected components .

Can we say that $A$ has $n$ connected components?

Comment: Are you asking if $\pi_n A \neq 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: "Let $A,B\in\mathbb C$": Do you mean $\subseteq$ instead of $\in$?

Answer (score 1):

No , $A$ might not have as many components as B.

Let $A$ be union of two closed disks $D_1$ and $D_2$ with $D_1 \cap D_2$ be a single point. Take $B= int(D_1) \cup int(D_2)=int(A)$. Then B has 2 components whereas A has only one. And clearly this example satisfies all of your conditons.

Comment: Thanks. If we consider, $A$ has $n+1$-connected components, can we say that, $B$ has $n+1$-connected components?

Comment: No that's clearly not true. Take B as one of the components of A. And one thing to mention remove the '-' from 'n- connected components' because 'n-connected' has another meaning

Comment: Dear Neel ,but in this paper, pages 16,17 (Theorem 12), why say this is right? ---- http://www.math.ntua.gr/~ppsarr/mcblp.pdf